# <template> + querySelector using :scope pseudo class works with document but not documentFragment

Tags: css-selectors, web-component, shadow-dom, documentfragment, html5-template

Depending on the content of a `<template>`, I want to wrap its contents in a container for easier/consistent traversal. If the contents are `<style>` and `<one-other-element>` at the top level, I'll leave it be. Otherwise, whatever's in there will get wrapped in a `<div>`.

Originally I made my code something like this:

```js
var hasCtnr = template.content.querySelector(':scope > :only-child, :scope > style:first-child + :last-child') != null;
```

But, I noticed it wasn't working -- that is, `hasCtnr` was always `false`. So, I made a [reduced test case (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/xcj2vc4y/). As you can see, `:scope` works with regular DOM elements. However, it doesn't seem to work with `DocumentFragment`s. **I know the technology is new/experimental but is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

If I use jQuery, it works... but my guess is because jQuery is doing something manually.

```js
var hasCtnr = !!$(template.content).children(':only-child, style:first-child + :last-child').length;
```

I only care about Chrome/[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) support, by the way.

Here's the jsfiddle inline:

```js
var nonTmplResult = document.querySelector('#non-template-result');
var tmplResult = document.querySelector('#template-result');

var grandparent = document.querySelector('#grandparent');
var parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
var child = document.querySelector('#child');

var who = grandparent.querySelector(':scope > div');
if (who === parent) {
    nonTmplResult.innerHTML = 'parent as expected, :scope worked';
} else if (who === child) {
    nonTmplResult.innerHTML = "child (unexpected), :scope didn't work";
}


var tmpl = document.querySelector('template');
var content = tmpl.content;

var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

var hasCtnr = content.querySelector(':scope > div'); // this and even ':scope div' results in null, 'div' results in DIV
tmplResult.innerHTML += hasCtnr == null ? "null for some reason, :scope didn't work" : hasCtnr.nodeName + ', :scope worked'; // Why is this null..?
tmplResult.innerHTML += '<br/>';

proto.createdCallback = function() {
    var clone = document.importNode(content, true);
    var root = this.createShadowRoot();
    root.appendChild(clone);
    var rootHasCtnr = root.querySelector(':scope > div'); // ':host > div' seems to work but I prefer this check to happen once (above) so createdCallback can be efficient as I'll likely have many custom elements
    tmplResult.innerHTML += rootHasCtnr == null ? "null again, :scope didn't work" : rootHasCtnr.nodeName + ', :scope worked'; // Why is this also null..?
};

document.registerElement('x-foo', { prototype: proto });
```

```css
#non-template-result {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
#template-result {
    background: green;
    color: springgreen;
}
* /deep/ * {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#grandparent {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="non-template-result">????</div>
<div id="template-result"></div>
<x-foo>
    <p>I should be dark golden rod with khaki text.</p>
</x-foo>

<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            background: blue;
            display: block;
        }
        :host > div > p {
            color: white;
        }
        ::content > p {
            background: darkgoldenrod;
            color: khaki;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <p>I should be blue with white text</p>
        <content></content>
    </div>
    
</template>

<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components#Enabling_Web_Components_in_Firefox">Enabling Web Components in Firefox</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug:

> The :scope CSS pseudo-class matches the elements that are a reference point for selectors to match against. In HTML, a new reference point can be defined using the `scoped` attribute of the `<style>` element. **If no such attribute is used on an HTML page, the reference point is the `<html>` element.**
>
> In some contexts, selectors can be matched with an explicit set of `:scope` elements. **This is a (potentially empty) set of elements that provide a reference point for selectors to match against**, such as that specified by the querySelector() call in [DOM], or the parent element of a scoped `<style>` element in [HTML5].

Since the `scoped` attribute is [no longer on any standards track](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#compat-desktop), this will only work a document with an `<html>` tag, which would preclude its use in a document fragment.

> Depending on the content of a `<template>`, I want to wrap its contents in a container for easier/consistent traversal. If the contents are `<style>` and `<one-other-element>` at the top level, I'll leave it be. Otherwise, whatever's in there will get wrapped in a `<div>`.

```js
var bar = document.body.getElementsByTagName("template");
var baz;

var iterator = function(value, index) {
  if(/<style>/.test(value.innerHTML) === false)
    {
    value.innerHTML = "\n<div>" + value.innerHTML + "</div>\n";
    }
  console.log(value.outerHTML);
  return value;
  };

bar.map = Array.prototype.map;
baz = bar.map(iterator);
```

```html
<template>
   <style>A</style> 
   <one-other-element>B</one-other-element> 
</template>

<template>
  <picture></picture>
</template>
```

**References**

- [MDN: CSS :scope pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope)
- [The Reference Element Pseudo-class: :scope](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-scope-pseudo)
- [Sizzle Issue #284: Selectors on document fragment](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/284)
- [HTMLTemplateElement.webidl](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/webidl/HTMLTemplateElement.webidl)

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#scoping "Some host applications may choose to scope selectors to a particular subtree or fragment of the document. The root of the scoping subtree is called the scoping root, and may be either a true element (the scoping element) or a virtual one (such as a DocumentFragment)." The quote from MDN seems to be based on an older version of selectors-4 that does not mention DocumentFragments.

Comment: Besides, I don't think that quote is relevant anyway. The :scope pseudo applies to scoped <style> elements in HTML, which implies it use in CSS, *in the context of HTML*. The DOM is an entirely different beast altogether (even though the DOM tree is built based on the HTML).

Comment: @BoltClock In the MDN doc, it has no alternative than the deprecated scoped attribute to determine context. How is that done currently, via source order or some other API?

Comment: In a <style> element, there is indeed no other way than the deprecated scoped attribute to scope a CSS rule to a specific element. But the question isn't about <style> elements or indeed CSS, it's about DocumentFragment.querySelector(), in which the :scope pseudo is expected to refer to that DocumentFragment node, at least according to the current selectors-4 and DOM texts. (My saying "in the context of HTML" was kind of problematic; ignore that bit.)

Answer (score 0):

In the statement:

```
var hasCtnr = template.content.querySelector(':scope > :only-child' ) //...
```

...the `:scope` pseudo-class represents the element calling `querySelector()`.

But a DocumentFragment (the type of `template.content`) is not an element (has no root element, no container) by definition, its `localName` attribute is *undefined*.

That's why this call will never select anything.

```js
var df = document.createDocumentFragment()
df.appendChild( document.createElement( 'div' ) )
var res = df.querySelector( ':scope div' )  

console.info( 'df.localName is %s', df.localName )
console.info( 'df.querySelector( :scope div ) returns %s', res )
```

A workaround could be to put the content in a `<div>`, perfom the call, then dismiss or use the `<div>` according to the result.